# How to replace serialize() form fields with apostrophe characters JQuery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization, coldfusion

I use JQuery to submit form data. In some of my fields apostrophe is allowed. On the server side I have validation and I notice that was failing. After I outputted value from one of my arguments with apostrophe I saw the difference between the quotes. Here is example:

```
'D’Ambrosio'
```

As you can see single quotes in front and at the end I have entered on the output for testing but one quote/apostrophe after `D` letter came from my argument value for that field. I'm wondering how I can fix this problem? Is there a way to prevent this conversion? Here is my ajax call:

```
var formData = $('#'+frmID).serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Components.cfc?method='+frmID,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(obj){
    if(obj.STATUS === 200){
        //Here I handle response 
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert(errorThrown);
});
```

Here is example of my serialize data:

```
frm_lname   John'
frm_fname   Boozer
frm_dob 08/01/2010
```

Comment: if it's just the apostrophe character a quick fix would be to simply escape the character after serializing to the formData variable. Just do a simple formData.replace("'","\'")

Comment: @zfrisch I have tried but still after submitting the form quote/apostrophe is different.

Comment: Okay. Could you give us some dummy serialized form data to work with?

Comment: @zfrisch I updated question with some form fields and the data. Data looks like that after I submit serialize form.

Comment: Your google search string is `coldfusion replace curly quotes`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you send your data you could encode your strings and then decode them on the server. This would help in preserving any "magic"/reserved characters like quotes.

```js
alert(encodeURIComponent('D’Ambrosio'));
```